# jQuery fadein fadeout text

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, fade

I have this at the moment: (the list is longer, but this is just one element)

```
<a href="Products.aspx" 
   onmouseover="onMouseOverCatDisplay(&quot;H5032.jpg&quot;, &quot;Go to: cars&quot;);"       
   onmouseout="onMouseOverCatDisplay(&quot;DSC_0414_SS.jpg&quot;, &quot;You see: bike&quot;);">Car</a>
```

and above the html, I have this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
// <![CDATA[
function onMouseOverCatDisplay(catimg, catnaam)
{
    $("#lh").stop().animate({ color: "#1C1C1C" }, 2000);
    $("#lh").html(catnaam);
    $("#lh").stop().animate({ color: "#DBDBD6" }, 2000);

    $("#imgCat").attr("src", catimg);
}
// ]]>
</script>
```

and this:

```
<h4 id="lh">Bikes</h4>
<img id="imgCat" src="img/bike.jpg" />
```

now everything works fine, but the animation does not work.

I'd like to fade out the h4, replace the text and then fade back in.

**EDIT** set the image source also with jQuery instead of javascript

**EDIT2**

rewritten the part so that it didn't use the mouseout and mouseover to trigger the javascript. but can't figure out a way to pass another paramter to the jquery (the image)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('div.divLeftCatMenu a').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({ color: '#E90E65', borderBottomColor: '#E90E65' }, 1000);
            var catn = $(this).attr('title');
            $("#lh").html(catn);
        },
        function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({ color: '#CCC6C6', borderBottomColor: '#3e3e3e' }, 1000);
            var catn = $("a.subCatLinksSelected").attr('title');
            $("#lh").html(catn);
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `&quote;` with `'`

Comment: In your javascript why do u use `this.document.getElementById(..)`?? I guess `document.getElementById(..)` is enough.

Comment: Hello Avinash, I got a 'unterminated string literal' in firefox errorconsole when i use the single quote and have replaced the getelementbyid part

Comment: @jp, `quote;` is parsed as `'`   by HTML parser & it's not javascript parsers job to parse it as `'`, if you got a 'unterminated string literal' it might be some wrong with in other parts of your script. I suggest you to install firebug : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/

Comment: Hello Avinash, i have firebug and have \" in my code. though it just works. only the animation doesn't.

Comment: @jp, oh sorry about the firebug thing, check my answer. Tell is that the animation you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

final Demo : **http://jsfiddle.net/VdFD9/**

If you would like to do this using `title` attribute, just modify the below code and set your title attributes as reference links(`image links` if you would like to).

**HTML** :

```
<a class="subCatLinksSelected" href="#" style="cursor:pointer;" title="cars"> cars </a> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
<a class="subCatLinksSelected" href="#" style="cursor:pointer;" title="bikes"> bikes</a>
<br />
<br />
<h4 id="lh">Bikes</h4>

<img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_men_imgCat" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6dec5eb240c49d979542d7cef64e9a8d?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" />
```

**javascript** :

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6dec5eb240c49d979542d7cef64e9a8d?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG";
arr[1] = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e555bd971bc2f4910893cd5b785c30ff?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG";
arr[2] = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/54d38793d7a407446999b33b81d607fd?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG";

//for instance i'm using an array to cache your image links
//if you can want these links as your anchor tag "title" attrib just modify the below code

 $(document).ready(function() {  

     var which_image = null; //detect which Image to use
       $(".subCatLinksSelected").hover(function() {

           var catn = $(this).attr('title');
           if(catn == 'cars') {        
               which_image = arr[1];
           } else {
               which_image = arr[2];
           }    
           onMouseOverCatDisplay(which_image, 'Go to: ' + catn,'#0099f9');

       },function() {

          var catn = $("a.subCatLinksSelected").first().attr('title');
          which_image = arr[0]
          onMouseOverCatDisplay(which_image,'You see: ' + catn, '#000');

       });
    });


 function onMouseOverCatDisplay(catimg, catnaam, color) {

    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_men_imgCat').attr('src',catimg);

    $("#lh")
        .css({opacity:0.2,color:"#1c1c1c"})
        .html(catnaam)
        .css({color: color})
        .stop()
        .animate({opacity:1 },2000);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Avinash, gonne take a closer look tomorrow (end of office day) will get back to this!

Comment: i have this now http://jsfiddle.net/zQzEY/1/
but i'd like the image also retrieved from the <a>

Comment: Thanks Avinash, will update my code so that it generates a javascript array filled with urls to images :)

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you are using jQuery, but attaching the events as inline javascript function calls. Don't do that. Attach your event to your DOM objects inside the document ready jQuery function.

Then you are using "document.getElementById" which is fine, but why not just use a standard jQuery selector to be consistent (which, in turn, will use getElementById for you).

Finally, what's likely happening is that your function is calling two animations at the same time. What you want is the second animation to happen only after the first one is finished. To ensure that, you want to call the first animation, then call the html swap and second animation via a callback function in the first. See the documentation for an example:

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Finally, while animating the color is fine, you may prefer to use fadeIn and fadeOut instead.

UPDATE:

Also, you have this:

```
 onmouseover="onMouseOverCatDisplay(&quot;H5032.jpg&quot;, &quot;Go to: cars&quot;);"
```

Try this instead:

```
 onmouseover="onMouseOverCatDisplay('H5032.jpg', 'Go to: cars');"
```

Comment: Hello DA. totally agree on your answer but i just migrated this old piece of javascript to jquery. but can't get the animation to work and don't know how i can pass parameters to the jquery method, since the name and image are variable per item (<a href=...>) of the list

Comment: Well, for the animation to work, read the link above that talks about the callback function. That should get you started. If you get stumped, post an update and we'll take a look!

Comment: DA, matschie gave a try with the callback function. but that didn't work. now i've rewritten parts so that it uses the hover function of jquery. but i can't figure out how i can pass two parameters to the jquery (image and name). will update above

Comment: If you're using the .hover event then that gets attached on document ready, so you aren't passing anything to it. What you can do is 'grab variables' when the hover event is called. You have to store the variables somehow. You could use jQuery's .data or you could use custom class names and parse them inside the hover function.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
$("#lh").stop().animate({ color: "#1C1C1C" }, 2000, function() {
    $("#lh").html(catnaam); 
    $("#lh").stop().animate({ color: "#DBDBD6" }, 2000); 
});
```

Because I think the two animations are overlapping eachother. This way the second one will start after the first one is finished.

Comment: sorry that didn't work. it worked at the first element. but didn't animate back to the original color.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.divLeftCatMenu a').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({ color: '#E90E65', borderBottomColor: '#E90E65' }, 1000);
        var catn = $(this).attr('title');
        $("#lh").html(catn);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({ color: '#CCC6C6', borderBottomColor: '#3e3e3e' }, 1000);
        var catn = $("a.subCatLinksSelected").attr('title');
        $("#lh").html(catn);
    });
```

Should work, however, if you want to access the image you'll need to bind it to each function... try this:

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('div.divLeftCatMenu a').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({ color: '#E90E65', borderBottomColor: '#E90E65' }, 1000);
            var catn = $(this).attr('title');
            $("#lh").html(catn);
        }**.bind($(*some selector for your image*))**,
        function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({ color: '#CCC6C6', borderBottomColor: '#3e3e3e' }, 1000);
            var catn = $("a.subCatLinksSelected").attr('title');
            $("#lh").html(catn);
        }**.bind($(*some selector for your image*))**);

You'll then be able to access the image in each function using ***this***, like ***this.src***